# How to restore prompt checkin dialog in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs

When doing a checkin in Visual Studio from the Pending Changes window I accidently checked the box "Don't prompt again" in the Check-in Confirmation dialog.
This prompt show you how many files you will checkin, I would like to restore it because I find it very useful to verify that I'm checkin the intended number of files.

I didn't find any options in the Tools > Options menu to restore it.

How could I restore it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found which registry key you need to modify to restore this option :

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\TeamFoundation\SourceControl\Behavior

Change the key value **ShowCheckinPrompt** to True and the "Check-in Confirmation" prompt will be back !

Answer (score 56):

Go to

> Tools -> Options -> Source Control -> Choose Visual Studio Team Foundation Server

Then check the box for 'Prompt before check-in from pending Changes window'

Comment: As a note this works on up to (at least) Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: Works in Visual Studio 2017 and 2019.

Comment: Works in Visual Studio 2022